# How can I fix a getpassWarning and use a getpass properlly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

So...I just want this. I'm trying to make a game 'Trusting Game' in Python. This is a game that you can betray your partner or not. here's the code I was making:

```
p1_point = 0
p2_point = 0
x = int(input("How many levels? "))
while x != 0:
    p1 = input("Player 1, pick yes to agree or no to betray. ") #I want to change this.
    p2 = input("Player 2, pick yes to agree or no to betray. ") #I want to change this.
    if p1 == "yes" and p2 == "yes":
        p1_point += 5
        p1_point += 5
    elif p1 == "yes" and p2 == "no":
        p1_point -= 2
        p2_point += 10
    elif p1 == "no" and p2 == "yes":
        p1_point += 10
        p2_point -= 2
    elif p1 == "no" and p2 == "no":
        p1_point -= 5
        p2_point -= 5
    print("Player 1 said {} and Player 2 said {}.".format(p1, p2))
    print("Player 1's score is now {} and Player 2's score is now {}.".format(p1_point, p2_point))
    x -= 1
if p1_point > p2_point:
    print("Player 1 wins!")
elif p1_point < p2_point:
    print("Player 2 wins!")
elif p1_point == p2_point:
    print("It's a tie!")
```

but I want to make the input like this:

```
****
```

so they won't cheat.

I saw someone saying to use the getpass module, I used it like this.

```
p1 = getpass.getpass(prompt = "Player 1, pick yes to agree or no to betray. ", stream = None)
p2 = getpass.getpass(prompt = "Player 2, pick yes to agree or no to betray. ", stream = None)
```

but there was a getpassWarning.

```
(from warnings module):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\getpass.py", line 100
return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Player 1, pick yes to agree or no to betray.
```

How can I fix this?
And how do I use the getpass?

Comment: see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getpass`

```
import getpass

pswd = getpass.getpass('Password:')
```

This should do the job. If you get a getPassWarning, you can try this

```
import sys
import msvcrt

passwor = ''
while True:
    x = msvcrt.getch()
    if x == '\r':
        break
    sys.stdout.write('*')
    passwor +=x

print '\n'+passwor
```

Comment: I used it but I got a getpassWarning so it didn't work... Is theer another way? (also, I use IDLE.)

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you're getting? @J.W.